# Keep getting DE variation of parameters questions wrong

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For several of my first attempts in solving nonhomogeneous equations through variation of parameters I always have the first term correct, but I have an extra term which is not part of the solution in the answer key.

I'm trying to solve:

$$y''+2y'+y=3e^{-t}$$

Homogenous solution is $y_c=c_1e^{-t}+c_2te^{-t}=0$
$$$$
Procedure for particular solution as follows:

$$Y'=u_1e^{-t}+u_2te^{-t}$$
$$Y''=-u_1e^{-1}+u_2e^{-t}-u_2te^{-t}$$
$$Y''=-u_1'e^{-t}+u_1e^{-t}+u_2'e^{-t}-u_2e^{-t}-u_2'te^{-t}-u_2e^{-t}+u_2te^{-t}$$

System of equations:

$$-u_1'e^{-t}+u_2'e^{-t}-u_2'te^{-1}=3e^{-t}$$
$$u_1'e^{-t}+u_2'te^{-t}=0$$

Solving for $u_1'$ and $u_2'$:

$$u_1'=-3t$$
$$u_2'=3t$$

Integration gives:

$$u_1=-\frac{3}{2}t^2$$
$$u_2=3t$$

Thus I get:

$$Y=-\frac{3}{2}t^2e^{-t}+3te^{-t}$$

However the answer is: $Y=\frac{3}{2}t^2e^{-t}$

What on Earth have I done?

Comment: $Y=-\frac{3}{2}t^2e^{-t}+3te^{-t}$ the term $3te^{-t}$ in your solution is absorbed by the homogneous solution  $y_c=c_1e^{-t}+c_2te^{-t}$

Comment: @user577215664 Thank you! This makes sense! Can't believe I missed this

Comment: Looks like you made a little  sign mistake ...

Comment: Yeah I thought this too. I think it was just a once off mistake since after taking what you said into account all of my other solutions are correct after making the necessary adjustment :)